# Managing Nuget packages for C# project present in multiple solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, nuget, projects-and-solutions

I am now on the phase of **refactoring madness** of a big project which has a lot of **legacy and unstable modules**. I've decided to **split the solution** that currently has ALL projects (so around 20 and there will be more because of unit test projects that would surely come in next months) chained in it to make it more independent and granular.

With this approach there are modules e.g. API clients that needs to be either referenced or added in multiple solutions.

The problem is that Nuget packages are getting restored only on the solution that it was added originally for the first time. So the simplest example:

Solution A:

------ ProjectA

------ APIClient

Solution B:

------ ProjectB

------ APIClient

Since we are not including packages folder it causes problems with Nuget packages:

1. Clone the repo.
2. Open Solution B, build it and restore the Nugets for solution.
3. Errors with packages of ClientAPI in Solution B.
4. Go to Solution A build it and restore the Nugets for solution
5. Get back to Solution B.
6. Nugets are restored for ClientAPI in Solution B and errors are gone.

Is there a way to somehow:

- Make the project using different path for each solution?
- Maybe chain solutions in build to make Solution A always build with Solution B? But that sounds like loosing some benefits of splitting this one big solution to smaller ones.
- Use any other approach to make it more granular and yet do not suffer problems with the necessity of rebuilding all? I've heard of private Nuget feeds, would that be an answer to this problem if my config allows that?

My config:

- VCS: TFS with TFVC
- IDE: Visual Studio Proffesional 2017
- Default package management format: Packages.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Managing Nuget packages for C# project present in multiple solutions

Thanks for you reply. I have reproduced this issue with two solutions, `SolutionA` with Project `APIClient`. And `SolutionB`, add the existing project `APIClient` in the `SolutionA` to the `SolutionB`.

Then if we restore the nuget package on the `SolutionB`, package in the project `APIClient` in the SolutionB will be restored in the `\packages` folder in the **SolutionB** folder by default rather than in the `SolutionA` folder.

In this case, the project `APIClient` still missing the `.dll` reference in the `SolutionB`, you still have to go to `SolutionA` and restore the nuget packages. That the reason why you got that issue.

To resolve this issue, you could add a `NuGet.Config` file next to the `SolutionA` and `SolutionB` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

So, the `\packages` folder not related to the solution file.

Besides, if you are interested, you can try to convert the `packages.config` to the `packagereference` for the project `APIClient`, with this setting, the nuget package will be saved in the global packages folder, `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is the exact solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not add package in the solution B ?

What package mode do you use ?

---

If you use "Package reference" mode, you must add package information in csproj of solution B.

If you use "Package config" mode, you must add package information in package.config file of solution B.

Comment: How can I check the package mode?

Comment: Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings : Default package manager format

Comment: Answer added to the question description. What do you mean by adding package to solution B? It is installed in the project that is added to Solution A and B.

Comment: You are right, the package.config file is inside the project and so available in both solutions. So, are you sure that the Soluation B is in "Package config" mode ? Other idea, perhaps you have a problem with the source of Nuget packages. Does the solution B have a nuget.config ? This file contains the sources of Nuget package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file

Comment: The location you specified in the previous comment is referring to global settings so the default mode. How can I check if the specific solution is in one mode or another?

Comment: You are right, it's a global parameter for the Nuget package manager of VisualStudio. It remains to check the Nuget source (nuget.config).