# NuGet Install - Package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' already exists in folder - csproj references another projects packages folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Instead of installing or updating a package NuGet Install references another projects packages folder. Is there anyway that I can make this stop? Happens when I use `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`, `Manage NuGet Packages...` and via `Package Manager Console`.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Output from Package Manager:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' with respect to project 'Project\Project.Domain.Business', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 21,42 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0'


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' with respect to project 'Project\Project.ServiceComponents', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 18,45 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0'
Removed package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' from Project.Clients.Admin
Package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\oscar\Documents\Solution\environment-setup\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.2.0' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'C:\Users\oscar\Documents\Solution\environment-setup\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\install.ps1'...
```

Previous .csproj:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
```

.csproj after:

```
<HintPath>..\..\..\environment-setup\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
```

Comment: Is your project included in a solution in a sibling directory? So it lives in `C:\Projects\Foo`, but is included in a solution in `C:\Projects\Bar`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yepp, I suspected it had something to do with this. Anyway I can get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038882/managing-nuget-packages-for-c-sharp-project-present-in-multiple-solutions). This is known behavior if you manage nuget packages for projects in different solution using `packages.config` format.

And to get around it, you need to define your custom `nuget.config` file for the solution scope.

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Or you can convert the `packages.config` format to `PackageReference` to resolve the issue.

(In VS2019, right-click `packages.config` file and choose migrate from `Packages.config` to `PackageReference`, for now this option not works for .net fx web apps, see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/))

Comment: This solution also worked on a WinForm application.  Thanks,